# how to remove full element from xml using python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

for example I have a XML

```
<parent class="alpha">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
<parent class="beta">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
<parent class="gamma">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
```

I want to remove full parent element if class match in parent element. let say for example class="beta".

then I want the updated XML like this.

```
<parent class="alpha">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
<parent class="gamma">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
```

I tried , but not able to get desired results.

```
with open("path/to/xml","w") as fil2:
        Soup = soup.find_all("parent ",{'class':'beta'})
        for i in Soup:
                i.decompose()
```

Comment: Looking at your XML, it seems invalid - for example `<subchild>`, `<child>` and `<parent>` tags are "crossed". Is it real-life example?

Comment: I just typed it manually wrong , but I corrected it now.

Comment: Running your code produced desired result, just remove space in `"parent " `: `soup.find_all("parent",{'class':'beta'})`

Comment: But When I am doing it . it is saving blank file.

Comment: I posted answer to show, how you can save the file.

Comment: Brilliant!. It worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the new file without specified tags, you can use this example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<parent class="alpha">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
<parent class="beta">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
<parent class="gamma">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for p in soup.find_all("parent",{'class':'beta'}):
    p.decompose()

with open('new_file.xml', 'w') as f_out:
    print(soup, file=f_out)
```

Saves `new_file.xml` with content:

```
<parent class="alpha">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>

<parent class="gamma">
<child>
<subchild>
</subchild>
</child>
</parent>
```